# Xpath: whitespace encoding

Tags: jcr

I need to create an XPath query to select a JCR node whose name contains a whitespace character.

For instance: `/jcr:root/foo bar/`

But that results in an invalid query.

How should whitespaces be encoded in an XPath query?

Comment: Space is not a valid character in an element name. Can you show the data?

Comment: Well, in fact I need to retrieve a JCR node (not an XML node)

Comment: Isn't it still an XML resource? Anyway, you could try `/jcr:root/{foo bar}/` or `/jcr:root/foo%20bar/` or `/jcr:root/foo&#x20;bar/` but I doubt it helps.

Comment: The repository I'm working with actually contains such nodes with whitespaces

Comment: XPath works on XML, not JCR. If you're not looking for an XML node, XPath can't help you.

Comment: Well, it seems to be supported in jackrabbit: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/EncodingAndEscaping

Comment: Jackrabbit's own augmented version of XPath perhaps, but no pure XPath knowledge/documentation will be able to help here.

Comment: Oh, then I should perhaps update my question to focus on jackrabbit

Comment: XPath is one of the query languages supported by JCR 1.0 implementations and many JCR 2.0 implementations (including Jackrabbit, ModeShape, and others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using something like this XPath query:

```
/jcr:root/foo_x0020_bar/
```

The [JSR-170](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170) (JCR 1.0) specification defines how XPath can be used to query a JCR repository, and even though [JSR-283](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283) (or JCR 2.0) deprecated XPath as a query language, many of the implementations still support XPath along with the other query languages (including the more powerful JCR-SQL2).

Now, regarding the rules for escaping characters in XPath, JSR-170 states the following in [Section 6.6.4.9](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/6.6.4.9_Escaping.html):

> The names of elements and attributes (corresponding to nodes and properties, respectively) within an XPath statement must correspond to the form in which they (notionally) appear in the document view. This means that spaces (and any other non-XML characters) within names must be encoded according to the rules described in 6.4.3 Escaping of Names.

[Section 6.4.3](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/6.4.3_Escaping_of_Names.html) defines how such characters are escaped in names:

> The escape character is the underscore (“_”). Any invalid character is escaped as *`_xHHHH_`*, where *HHHH* is the four-digit hexadecimal UTF-16 code for the character. When producing escape sequences the implementation should use lowercase letters for the hex digits a-f. When unescaping, however, both upper and lowercase alphabetic hexadecimal characters must be recognized.

Although you didn't ask about it, you can easily do the same query in JCR-SQL2:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE ISSAMENODE('/foo_x0020_bar')
```